# Length = 'serverStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to create a socket coonection with the server. For that I am passing an xml and it is stored in the string ngconnect. Now while debbuging the code 
I found the exception in serverstream.Write  as

> 'serverStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

What may be the reason of such an exception and how do I remove them.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            portadd = textBox2.Text;

            ip = textBox1.Text;
            port = Convert.ToInt32(portadd);
            clientSocket.Connect(ip, port); 
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ngconnect);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, 200);
            serverStream.Flush();

            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            msg(returndata);
            textBox3.Focus();

    }
```

Comment: Please show *where* you're getting the exception (and please improve your code formatting at the same time). As an aside, you're ignoring the return value of `Read`, which is never a good idea - and you're also performing IO in your UI thread, which will make the UI unresponsive while it's doing the IO.

Comment: I am getting the exception at line serverStream.write(outStream,0,200);

Comment: Please put the full stack trace in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, the application did not throw the exception, but you were debugging, inspected `serverStream` and saw the exception in the debugger.

This is normal behavior - Visual Studio attempts to show all property values, and `NetworkStream` does not support the `Length` property. See [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information:

> NotSupportedException: A class derived from Stream does not support seeking.

You can inspect the `CanSeek` property of any `Stream` to verify whether it supports seeking, and so the `Length` property.

Comment: Yes you are right. That was an internal exception. I just came to know that the server I am trying to connect is set to read the first 4 byte of data as the length of the stream which I was not sending.